# How to insert an if on a hash-map in clojure

Tags: clojure, hashmap, structure

This is valid:

```
{:a :v (if true :f) :r }
```

This is not

```
{:a :v (if true {:f :r}) }
```

Since it wants to put a new hashmap in the structure

I need to return in that `if` a special structure (that I have forgotten its name)
that contains the key and value so it gets inserted in the hash map.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second case fails not because the `if` form is returning the wrong type of value but because the map contains an odd number of items. Map literals must contain an even number of forms, and the `if` is a single form.

There are several ways to add things to maps in Clojure.

You can use [`conj`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/conj) with either a vector or a map argument:

```
(conj {:a :v} [:f :r])  ;;=> {:f :r, :a :v}
(conj {:a :v} {:f :r})  ;;=> {:f :r, :a :v}
```

You can use [`assoc`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/assoc) with the key and val as separate arguments:

```
(assoc {:a :v} :f :r)   ;;=> {:f :r, :a :v}
```

Or you can use [`merge`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/merge) with two (or more) maps as arguments:

```
(merge {:a :v} {:f :r}) ;;=> {:f :r, :a :v}
```

The special structure you're thinking of may be a `MapEntry`. That's what the items are in a seq created by calling `seq` on a map.

For instance:

```
(seq a-map)                ;;=> ([:a :v] [:f :r])
(first (seq a-map))        ;;=> [:a :v]
(-> a-map seq first class) ;;=> clojure.lang.MapEntry
```

Map entries look and behave just like vectors, with one addition. You can use the `key` and `val` functions to access the key and val respectively (effectively equivalent to `(get map-entry 0)` and `(get map-entry 1)`).

```
(key map-entry) ;;=> :a
(val map-entry) ;;=> :v
```

You can `conj` a map entry onto a map just like you can a vector.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for MapEntry. And what I wanted was completely impossible. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Conditional threading macros are often helpful for this sort of thing. *Especially* if you are already using them to apply a series of transform to your data. Here's a sketch of creating http headers

```
(let [compressed? true
      custom-header? false]

    (-> {:content-type "text/plain"}
        (cond-> compressed? (assoc :content-encoding "gzip"))
        (cond-> custom-header? (assoc :my-custom-header "foo"))
        clojure.walk/stringify-keys))

;=> {"content-encoding" "gzip", "content-type" "text/plain"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you need?

```
(merge {:a :v} (if true {:f :r}))
=> {:f :r, :a :v}
```